# Wordpress/Pardot/Contact Form 7 (Need plugin which validated numbers and emails)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, email-verification, pardot

I am new to this, so sorry for my ignorance if it doesn't make sense. We are using Pardot form handlers and CF7 on Wordpress on our landing page. We need another plugin (on either WP side or Pardot side) to be able to verify people's numbers and email addresses to stop the fake leads coming through. Can anyone help :)

Comment: Please try to show a little more research effort in your question to increase the likelihood of getting a reply.

Comment: Don't just post question. You should also include some of your researches

Comment: I did. I just wanted the best possible option, mate. Didn't have to reply if you didn't think 'I did enough research'.

Answer (score 0):

For validating the email address coming from Contact Form 7, you can try to use [MailboxValidator Email Validator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailboxvalidator-email-validator/). This is a WordPress plugin that can help to validate invalid email address coming from the form.